# How in Vue Js to asynchronously receive and then filter data from GraphQl with Pinia

Tags: vue.js, graphql, pinia

When I have get data on downloading page, I have problem with function useQuery, it downloaded not await data and I see error because data not ready to be use.

I used function useLazyQuery -- it not worked, not working and await useQuery.
Problem in getters method filterItems - when download page filterItems return null

My code template with Pinia and graphQl, Problem in await data.

```
<template>

<div class=" text-3xl leading-[44px] text-left">{{  HomePage.getNameItem() }}</div>

 <div class="inputs_block">

    <div class="name_color mb-4">
        <span class="name text-base leading-6 text-black">Цвет:</span>
        <span class="value text-sm  leading-18px text-[#707070] ml-[5px]">{{ HomePage.activeColor }} </span>

    </div>

    <div class=" flex gap-x-0.5 flex-wrap ml-[-5px]">
        
        <span
            v-for="(color, idx) in filterItems"
            :key="idx"
            :class="HomePage.activeColor == color.colorName ? 'border-[#CAA381]' : 'border-[white]'"
            @click="HomePage.getSku(color.title, color.surfaceName, color.colorName, color.image, color.morePhoto)"
            class="group w-[52px] h-[52px] relative flex justify-center items-center -mt-2 mb-2.5 rounded-[7px]  border-2 border-solid  hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-2 hover:border-solid hover:border-[#CAA381]"><img class="rounded w-[42px] h-[42px]"
                :src=color.colorUrl alt="">
            <p class="group-hover:block bg-[#F5F3F1] hidden absolute text-xs leading-[14px] text-center text-black bottom-[-30px] w-[max-content] z-[1] px-[3px] py-[5px] rounded-lg">{{ color.colorName }}</p>
        </span>

    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia"
import { useHomePage } from '@/stores/HomePageStore'
const HomePage = useHomePage()
const { filterItems } = storeToRefs(HomePage)
</script>
```

and file store with Pinia

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia"
import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { ITEMS_QUERY, SKU_QUERY} from '@/graphql/queries'

export const useHomePage = defineStore('homeStore',{

    state: () => {
     
       return {
      
        resultSku: useQuery(SKU_QUERY,{ itemName: '' }),
        resultItems: useQuery(ITEMS_QUERY,{ itemBrand: "Estera" }),


}

    },
  
    getters: {
     
        filterItems: (state) => {return [...new Map(state.resultItems.result.items.map(item =>[item['colorName'], item])).values()]},

    },

actions: {

getNameItem(){

    if(!this.nameItem) this.nameItem = this.filterItems[0].title

    return this.nameItem
},

async getSku(nameItem, surface, color, imageItem, imagesItem){
   
    const dataQuery = useQuery(SKU_QUERY, { itemName: nameItem });
    this.resultSku = dataQuery;
    this.activeSurface = surface;
    this.nameItem = nameItem;
    this.activeColor = color;
    this.imageItem = imageItem;
    this.imagesItem = imagesItem;
    this.windowsSillLength = 100;
    this.mainColl = 1;

},

})
```

Comment: `useQuery` returns an object with different properties. If you want to access to the response data, use [`dataQuery.result`](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-query.html#return).

Comment: Problem in get data when download page and dataQuery.result ==  null

Comment: Of course, because the query isn't over yet. You have to wait for the `result` to be filled, with a `watcher` for example.

Comment: @Kapcash When I use watcher I have error, apollo client is not connect

Comment: @Kapcash "apollo client with id default not found. use provideapolloclient() if you are outside of a component setup."

Comment: This error is unrelated to the original question. Please follow carefully the vue-apollo documentation and consider opening another question. I don't have enough context and code here to help you.

Comment: @Kapcash When I add `console.log(resultItems.result.loaded)` in getters method `filterItems` before `return`. I sow `true`, but I need sow `false`. If I add `watch` in template file I have error `apollo client with id default not found. use provideapolloclient() if you are outside of a component setup.` . My Question - How I need use `await` or another timer it wait than data full downloaded.